# Find specific text in a paragraph by line

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if the question is worded weird but here is what I'm trying to do. I have to gather a specific line of info from a webpage. What I am having trouble with is I can not figure out the right selector to use, `eq()` is not working . Here is the source from the page I'm trying to get the info from.

```
<div class="info" id="Data">
Domain Name: example.com
<br>
Registry: 12345
<br>
```

When I inspect element I get div#Data.info (text) I have tried `$('div#info.Data').eq(1).text()` and a few other combinations. I an new to scripting and the (text) part is what is I think is throwing me off.

Comment: Are you able to return all of the text in that div?  If so, you may want to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.  This way you can then us `.split()` with the `<br>`s.  You'd probably say `var line_1 = $('div#info').html().split('<br>')[0]`

Comment: To clarify, you want to retrieve the first line of an element using jQuery / JS? Is it possible you create paragraphs instead of separating them with line breaks?

Comment: You may try like this, `var x= $("div#Data").text().split("\n")`. `x` will contain array of lines from that div.

Comment: you have your id/classes reversed. it's `div#Data.info`, not the other way around.

Comment: If i use  $('div#info.Data').text(); it returns the complete paragraph. I Had tried .split but it looks like i was using it incorrectly I tried .split('br'). What you said with the .html().split('<br>') worked. I'm just learning this and I appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at your jQuery:

```
$('div#info.Data') // Gets <div> with id="info" and class="Data"
                   // ^ You have id and class reversed!
.eq(1)             // This gets the 2nd element in the array
                   // ^ You only tried to get 1 element. What is the 2nd?
.text()            // Returns combined text of selected elements
```

Also there's another issue. Your text is not in its own element. In order to get the textnodes in your current element, you could call [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/). jQuery does not treat text nodes like regular elements, though, so I would be careful doing any additional operations on them.

You can retrieve the text like such:

```
$("#Data").contents().eq(0).text() // -> 'Domain Name: example.com'
$("#Data").contents().eq(2).text() // -> 'Registry: 12345'
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf4s16x1/)**

Comment: I do not have access to change html.. It's a work project I have to go to the same website a few thousand times and copy one line of info. What im doing is making a greasemonkey script to  GM_xmlhttpRequest the info and fill it on another page so this will save me a ton of time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have you're `id` and `class` the wrong way round but this is a simple fix.

An alternative to your solution is to grab all the content, split it out into an array and then clean the empty strings caused by the new lines and `<br />` tags.

This can then be used in any matter you like.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = $('div#Data.info').eq(0).text();
  var lines = content.split("\n").filter(Boolean)
  console.log(lines);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info" id="Data">
Domain Name: example.com
<br>
Registry: 12345
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry about that , I had changed the original code so it was not oblivious what web site it was from and i accidentally switched the order around. I edited the original question so they are in the right order now. Thanks for the answer that worked as well.